glossaries for an unsophisticated use case?
I'm writing a book in LaTeX for which I need to include a glossary for terms and acronyms. I don't need for it to be "active" in the sense that an ebook version would click from a use of a word in the body to its definition in a glossary. I only want to have a flat glossary "available" as a section at the end of the book. I would populate it by hand as I go along.
I think from the voluminous literature that the glossaries package does a lot more than what I need. Is it worth trying to use in that case? Or should I just make it by hand?
I've gone so far as to create a pulldown in the typeset menu but the more I mess with examples, the more I wonder if I really need this otherwise really sophisticated engine.
thanks

Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean with "is it worth ..."? That depends on your opinion, I think.

There's a lot of overhead in using glossaries. Multiple passes, maybe passing through the index tool for sorting, maybe using the command line. I think that it's meant to form links from an instance of a word in the body with the definition in the glossary. But I can't really be sure since the examples I can find are so trivial.

Maybe you are looking for nomenclature.  This mean also run makeindex, but with  respect the latex code  is rather simple.

thanks. you're right, this might be all I need. I've made it work on a simple test and I'll now look at the manual!
